# ¿Diferencia en Java y JS a la hora de crear una clase e instanciarla?

Tags: java, javascript, api, mongodb

Estoy usando JS para realizar una API y por más que pruebo no consigo entender por qué, al realizar una petición POST para crear un usuario me dice que Usuario no es un constructor.

Soy "nuevo" en JS y tengo en la cabeza la creación de clases/constructores que usa Java, por lo que no entiendo *porqué en JS no funciona de la misma manera*. Quizás se me escapa algo o quizás **no lo entiendo bien**.

Os adjunto el código con el que estoy trabajando a modo de ejemplo para intentar entenderlo:

Como base de datos uso *MONGO*

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var usuarioSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String,
    companyName: String
    //id: Integer,
    //telephone: Integer,
    //data: String

});
module.export = mongoose.model('Usuario', usuarioSchema);
```

Esta sería el fichero donde supuestamente guardo el usuario en mi base de datos.

```
'use strict'

var Usuario = require('../Usuario.js');

function saveUsuario(request, res) {
    var usuario = new Usuario(); 
    var params = request.body; 


    usuario.name = params.name;
    usuario.surname = params.surname;
    usuario.companyName = params.companyName;


    usuario.save(function (err, usuarioStored) {
        if (err) { //Si se producen errores al guardar un usuario
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Error al guardar el usuario'
            });
        } //Si no se producen errores al guardar
        res.status(200).send({
            usuario: usuarioStored
        });

    });
}
```

Al utilizar algún software de peticiones HTTP (yo utilizo [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/)) me dice que Usuario no es un constructor. No logro entender por qué no es un constructor si realmente estoy guardando en mi base de datos un nuevo Usuario con los tres campos especificados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No entiendo porqué en JS no funciona de la misma manera

¿Por qué tendría que hacerlo? Son lenguajes completamente diferentes que nacieron con necesidades y que cumplen con objetivos diferentes. Es como comparar Peras con Manzanas y decir por qué no saben igual si ambas son frutas.

Java implementa la POO de manera muy diferente a JavaScript. Este último implementa una POO prototipada, que es muy diferente a la POO clásica que implementa Java. De hecho, en JavaScript **no existe el concepto de clases**.

---

Hecha la aclaración, vamos por tu error. Tu error es que no estás exportando nada. Node.js implementa en su código fuente a CommonJS, el cual es una librería para modularización de código, permitiéndote escribir código JavaScript en "módulos" independientes entre sí, los cuales pueden ser exportados e importados desde cualquier lugar. Sin la existencia de CommonJS, **tendrías que escribir todo en un solo archivo**, dificultando enormemente tareas post desarrolo.

Para exportar un módulo en CommonJS se usa `module.exports` y no `module.export` **como estás usando**:

```
 module.exports = moongose.model('Usuario', usuarioSchema);
```

Esto pone el archivo en el repositorio de CommonJS para que pueda ser importado. En tu caso no estás exportando nada, entonces, cuando importas `Usuario`, estás importando el objeto CommonJS y **este no es un constructor**.

Recuerda también que de esta forma **se exporta un objeto para que esté disponible de forma predeterminada**. Existe también la siguiente forma para exportar:

```
var model = moongose.model('Usuario', usuarioSchema);
exports.model = model;
```

En este caso, `model` no estará disponible como opción por defecto para importar, si no que se exportará todo el objeto de exportación conteniendo `model`:

```
var Usuario = require('../Usuario').model;
```

---

**Nota:** no es necesario agregar el sufijo `.js` al importar.

Comment: Una explicación perfecta e impecable, conoces bien la teoría pero mucho mejor la práctica. La verdad que mejor imposible, muchas gracias @GustavoGarcia. Entendí como funciona y corregí mi error, un saludo.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido @AAg. Si te sirvió mi respuesta, no olvides votar (cuando puedas) o marcarla. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con el post anterior Java es orientado a objeto, Javascript es un lenguaje basado en prototipos.

Un POJO es un objeto que instancias (si no esta marcado como abstracto) y posee caracteristicas (atributos encapsulados privados) y comportamientos que son metodos que pueden ser publicos o privados, cuando creas el objeto usando su constructor, puedes usar sus metodos publicos.

Ejemplo:

MiObjeto miObjeto = new MiObjeto();

miObjeto.miMetodoDeInstancia();

En javascript creas prototipos que acoplas a "objetos", por ejemplo:
Si quieres crear una nueva funcionalidad para el "objeto" String de javascript harias algo asi:

String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return (this.length === 0 || !this.trim());
};

Y lo puedes usar asi:

"".isEmpty(); <-- Devuelve true

Comment: Gracias por la explicación @JorgeSainz, me ha servido para aclararme. Un saludo